# RestKit 0.20: How to POST/GET more than 1 managed object without a wrapper class?

Tags: restkit

Currently I have several instances where I need to send a group of objects to the server:

```
{
    "things": [
        {
            //object stuff
        },
        {
            //object stuff
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

So what I've been doing is defining an intermediate object `MyThingPayload`

```
@interface MyThingPayload
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *things;
@end
```

And then when mapping

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:NSClassFromString(@"MyThingPayload")];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"things"
                                                                        toKeyPath:@"things"
                                                                      withMapping:[self entityMappingForManagedThingObject]]];
```

Seems like unnecessary overhead.  Is there a way to do this without the intermediate object that holds an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate object to provide the structure to be used during serialisation. It doesn't need to be a custom class though, it can just be an `NSDictionary` containing the correct key and `NSArray` value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this?  Would I say `[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:NSClassFromString(NSDictionary)]` and then keep the same property mapping?

Comment: Yes. Or use `[RKObjectMapping  requestMapping]` which is a shortcut (for `NSMutableDictionary`).