# RestKit 0.20 - POST multiple objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit-0.20

I am creating a task application which has offline mode. I have almost created online mode successfully using RestKit.

While in offline mode, I am setting `isSync` attribute to `false` for each object, so that when network is available I could fetch these unsynced objects with predicate and POST them to server.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to `POST` an array of these objects to server in one go using RestKit.

Does RestKit support this? Or is there any better way to implement offline support using RestKit?

**Update:**

I have found a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232620/restkit-0-20-how-to-post-get-more-than-1-managed-object-without-a-wrapper-class), of creating an intermediate `Entity` (with its own mapping) that has a property of `NSArray` which can be POSTed to server.

But I have many entities (notes, tasks, comments ... etc) that needs offline functionality, do I have to create an additional intermediate Entity for each of my original Entity? (so that response of each can be mapped correctly in my original Entity)

**Update 2:**

After visiting [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/398), I have found that POSTing an array of multiple objects in supported now in RestKit 0.20.0. But whenever I have POST an array of objects, no parameters are sent to server. This is how I am doing:

```
[DBTasks createTask:task attachments:nil completionHandler:^(DBTasks *task, NSError *error) {
            isPosting = NO;
            [self setLoadingState:NO];
            if (!error) {
                KLog(@"task is %@", task); // works perfect
                [self.tasksArray insertObject:task atIndex:0];
                [self reloadTasks];

            } else {
                KLog(@"error %@", error);
            }
        }];
```

This is my method for actually sending POST request:

(Just consider `else` part)

```
+ (void)createTask:(DBTasks *)task attachments:(NSArray *)attachments completionHandler:(void (^)(DBTasks *, NSError *))completionHandler {

    if (attachments != nil && attachments.count > 0) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:task
                                                                                               method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                                 path:URL_TASKS
                                                                                           parameters:@{@"total_attachments": [NSNumber numberWithInt:attachments.count]}
                                                                            constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                                                                                int counter = 0;
                                                                                for (NSDictionary *dic in attachments) {
                                                                                    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([dic objectForKey:@"image"], 0.7)
                                                                                                                name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment[%i]", counter]
                                                                                                            fileName:[dic objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                                                                            mimeType:@"image/jpg"];

                                                                                    counter++;
                                                                                }
                                                                            }];

        RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                                   managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]
                                                                                                                success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                                                                                    KLog(@"success");
                                                                                                                    completionHandler((DBTasks *)[mappingResult firstObject], nil);

                                                                                                                } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                                    KLog(@"fail");
                                                                                                                    completionHandler(nil, error);
                                                                                                                }];
        [operation start];

    }

    // without attachment
    else {
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:task path:URL_TASKS parameters:nil
                                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                completionHandler((DBTasks *)[mappingResult firstObject], nil);
                                            }
                                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                completionHandler(nil, error);
                                            }];
    }
}
```

Following is the mapping:

```
- (RKEntityMapping *)tasksMapping {

    RKEntityMapping *tasksMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DBTasks" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
    tasksMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
    tasksMapping.deletionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shouldBeDeleted = 1"];
    [tasksMapping setModificationAttributeForName:@"updated_at"];
    tasksMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

    [tasksMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"completed_at", @"created_at", @"due_date", @"id", @"note", @"private", @"send_email", @"status", @"title", @"type", @"updated_at", @"user_id", @"parent_id", @"total_attachments", @"url", @"from", @"total_comments"]];

    [tasksMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"deleted": @"shouldBeDeleted"}];


    [tasksMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"attachments" mapping:[self attachmentsMapping]];
    [tasksMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"owner" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [tasksMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"additional_owners" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
    [tasksMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"tags" mapping:[self tagsMapping]];

    return tasksMapping;
}
```

The same mapping is used for POST/PUT/DELETE but with calling `inverseMapping` method.

Now when I call `postObject` with an array:

```
[DBTasks createTasks:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:task, task, nil] attachments:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
            isPosting = NO;
            [self setLoadingState:NO];
            if (!error) {
                KLog(@"Array of objects is %@", array);
                [self.tasksArray insertObject:task atIndex:0];
                [self reloadTasks];

            } else {
                KLog(@"error %@", error);
            }
        }];
```

with almost previous method:

```
+ (void)createTasks:(NSArray *)tasksArray attachments:(NSArray *)attachments completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:tasksArray path:URL_TASKS parameters:nil
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                            completionHandler(mappingResult.array, nil);
                                        }
                                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            completionHandler(nil, error);
                                        }];
}
```

The application is terminated

```
2014-05-05 16:18:30.692 MyApp[8195:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:377 Executing mapping operation for representation: (
        {
        attachments =         (
        );
        "completed_at" = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "<null>";
        deleted = 0;
        "due_date" = "<null>";
        from = "Stand-alone task";
        id = "<null>";
        note = "<null>";
        owner = "<null>";
        private = 0;
        "send_email" = "<null>";
        status = "<null>";
        tags =         (
        );
        title = "<null>";
        "total_attachments" = 0;
        "total_comments" = 0;
        type = Task;
        "updated_at" = "<null>";
        url = "http://10.28.79.98:3000/workspace/tasks?open=task_";
        "user_id" = 26894;
    }
)
 and targetObject: (null)
2014-05-05 16:18:30.693 MyApp[8195:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:297 Found mappable collection at keyPath '': (
        {
        attachments =         (
        );
        "completed_at" = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "<null>";
        deleted = 0;
        "due_date" = "<null>";
        from = "Stand-alone task";
        id = "<null>";
        note = "<null>";
        owner = "<null>";
        private = 0;
        "send_email" = "<null>";
        status = "<null>";
        tags =         (
        );
        title = "<null>";
        "total_attachments" = 0;
        "total_comments" = 0;
        type = Task;
        "updated_at" = "<null>";
        url = "http://10.28.79.98:3000/workspace/tasks?open=task_";
        "user_id" = 26894;
    }
)
2014-05-05 16:18:30.694 MyApp[8195:f03] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'DBTasks' 
2014-05-05 16:18:30.694 MyApp[8195:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    attachments =     (
    );
    "completed_at" = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "<null>";
    deleted = 0;
    "due_date" = "<null>";
    from = "Stand-alone task";
    id = "<null>";
    note = "<null>";
    owner = "<null>";
    private = 0;
    "send_email" = "<null>";
    status = "<null>";
    tags =     (
    );
    title = "<null>";
    "total_attachments" = 0;
    "total_comments" = 0;
    type = Task;
    "updated_at" = "<null>";
    url = "http://10.28.79.98:3000/workspace/tasks?open=task_";
    "user_id" = 26894;
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x10598240 objectClass=DBTasks propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599660 completed_at => completed_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599670 created_at => created_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599680 due_date => due_date>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599690 id => id>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996a0 note => note>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996b0 private => private>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996c0 send_email => send_email>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996d0 status => status>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996e0 title => title>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x105996f0 type => type>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599700 updated_at => updated_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599710 user_id => user_id>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599720 parent_id => parent_id>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599730 total_attachments => total_attachments>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599740 url => url>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599750 from => from>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599760 total_comments => total_comments>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10599870 deleted => shouldBeDeleted>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x1059b1c0 attachments => attachments>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x1059c5f0 owner => owner>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x1059dca0 additional_owners => additional_owners>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x105a1e00 tags => tags>"
)>
2014-05-05 16:18:30.695 MyApp[8195:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-05-05 16:18:30.696 MyApp[8195:340b] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'DBTasks': {
    "additional_owners" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "additional_owners";
    };
    attachments =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = attachments;
    };
    "completed_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "completed_at";
    };
    "created_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "created_at";
    };
    "due_date" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "due_date";
    };
    from =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = from;
    };
    id =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = id;
    };
    note =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = note;
    };
    owner =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = DBContacts;
        name = owner;
    };
    "parent_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "parent_id";
    };
    private =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = private;
    };
    "send_email" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "send_email";
    };
    shouldBeDeleted =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = shouldBeDeleted;
    };
    status =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = status;
    };
    tags =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = tags;
    };
    title =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = title;
    };
    topic =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = DBTopics;
        name = topic;
    };
    "total_attachments" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "total_attachments";
    };
    "total_comments" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "total_comments";
    };
    type =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = type;
    };
    "updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "updated_at";
    };
    url =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = url;
    };
    "user_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "user_id";
    };
}
2014-05-05 16:18:30.698 MyApp[8195:340b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x034721e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be48e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x034fbeb8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 888
    3   MyApp                         0x002dad3a __61-[RKPropertyInspector(CoreData) propertyInspectionForEntity:]_block_invoke61 + 154
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04ce17b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04cf64d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04ce4047 _dispatch_queue_drain + 452
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04ce3e42 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04ce4de2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 78
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x04ce5127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x05025dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x05029cce start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No, you don't. Show your model structure, required JSON sample and the code you tried using an array of objects (and describe what it did wrong).

Comment: @Wain, thanks for reply. Actually I have not implemented it, because I don't know how to do that. The `postObject` accepts single object, and there is no `postObjects` method available. I have tried creating an array of objects and provide it to `postObject`. The server has not written to handle this request, so I am waiting for server guy to for that. But I am still wondering if POSTing an array like this would reverse map exactly my local objects and update them. Am I going wrong?

Comment: Posting an array is correct. The mapping controls what is taken from each object in the array to the JSON.

Comment: @Wain, I am trying to POST an array of objects to server, but server side guy says he doesn't receive any parameters. When I POST a single object, it works perfect. Any idea what can be wrong? I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to sending an array, it is due to your core data stack setup. There is a big difference between your two cases. The one which works uses the default context from magical record. The one which doesn't uses the object manager and it's associated object store - which would seem to not be configured.

From the code and error, posting a single task without attachments should also fail.

Check your core data stack creation and the association with the object manager.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have already setup core data stack, as suggested by Blake https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord

and all the web service requests and offline `NSPredicate` fetchings are working good. Just POSTing an array of objects is not working.

As I didn't find any example of POSTing an array like this before, so just wanted to confirm is this really works? Am I missing something?

Comment: This part of the log `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'DBTasks'` means the stack or how you use it isn't correct

Comment: I am really tired of this error :(. When I call `postObject:task` it works perfect, but when I call `postObject:@[task]`, it doesn't. Now I will look more into cause of error you mentioned above.

Comment: Hey @Wain, I have observed that when I POST an array of objects, then in `RKObjectManager.m` class, `BOOL isManagedObjectRequestOperation = (containsEntityMapping || [object isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]);` is always `false`. Because [object isKindOfClass] is `NSArray` not `NSManagedObject`. So RestKit takes it as a NSObject operation instead of NSManagedObject operation. And code goes in else part `// Non-Core Data operation
        operation = [self objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];` Can this be cause of error you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. Consider raising an issue on github. You could use `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:` to work around it.

Comment: even I use `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` application doesn't crash any more, but the server still doesn't get any parameter in request. Any idea what can be possibilities? In my log I have request.body as expected `request.body=[{"user_id":0,"id":0,"send_email":false,"total_attachments":0,"attachments":[],"parent_id":0,"total_comments":0,"status":0,"additional_owners":[],"tags":[],"title":"Test task"},{"user_id":0,"id":0,"send_email":false,"total_attachments":0,"attachments":[],"parent_id":0,"total_comments":0,"status":0,"additional_owners":[],"tags":[],"title":"Test task"}]`

Comment: So the server receives a request, but it is empty? The log looks good. Use Charles to check it's sent/.

Comment: yes, this is log by server side `#<Hashie::Mash route_info=version=, method=POST, path=/tasks(.:format)>`. Let me try Charles.

Comment: Do you think I need to modify `RKRequestDescriptor` for array of objects?

Comment: Charles says that data is being sent correctly, now my web service developer is feeling what I was feeling in last 2 days :)